# MUI component on a same line

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a text dropdown menu with code `

```
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from '@mui/material'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// Define the options for the dropdown menu
const options = [
  'Never',
  'Every Minute',
  'Every 2 Minute',
  'Every 5 Minute',
  'Every 10 Minute',
  'Every 30 Minute',
]

const CycleDropdown: React.FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('Never')

  const handleChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>,
    newValue: string | null
  ) => {
    setValue(newValue || '')
  }

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          sx={{
            mt: '10px',
          }}
          {...params}
          label="Select Cycle"
          size="small"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default CycleDropdown
```

`and now I want to render this on other page with code`

```
 <Grid container marginTop={2}>
          <Grid item lg={4} xl={4} md={4} xs={2}>
            <Typography variant="h3" color="inherit">
              Daily Summary
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item lg={4} xl={4} md={4} xs={2}>
            <Typography variant="h3">{currentDate}</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h3">
              Daily Summary Update Cycle: <CycleDropdown />
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

`
I want to show all this 3 grid item  on a same line but I cannot do it. I know it is a simple task but I can't do it. I am learning the whole react and mui thing so please help me. ( the text "Daily Summary Update Cycle:" appears right above the dropdown menu I have created. I want to show them as [image: I want like this]
but I have them like [image: my line of things]. please help me fix it

Answer (score 1):

I hope this gonna help you.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnlVR.png)

```
  <Grid container marginTop={2}>
    <Grid sx={styles} item lg={6} xl={4} md={4} xs={2}>
      <Typography variant="h5" color="inherit">
        Daily Summary&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
        {"2-06-2023"}
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid sx={styles} lg={6} sm={4} item>
      <Typography variant="h6">
        Daily Summary Update Cycle:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </Typography>
      <CycleDropdown />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

and style is very simple, you can change font sizes and also adjust width of auto complete next to mt property.

const styles = {
display: "flex",
alignItems: "center",
};